# Anime with kawaii cat girl being patted

Tags: yozakura-quartet

[image]

Sooooo Kawaiiiiiii

Does anyone know what anime this is

Comment: OMG, she is one of the cutest girls in anime ever!

Comment: @GaoWeiwei there's cuter but given the scene it's quite irresistible not to begin to bleed from an overload of cuteness

Answer (score 11):

This is [Ao Nanami](http://myanimelist.net/character/14945/Ao_Nanami) from [Yozakura Quartet](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Yozakura_Quartet)

[image]

You can find this by using [IQDB](http://iqdb.org/?url=http%3A%2F%2Fi.stack.imgur.com%2FCyVXO.gif) and then going to a result (some sites may not be SFW) and look at the image tags. You can see that the gif is tagged as "Yozakura Quartet".

Comment: addition to answer, it's from Yozakura Quartet: Hana no Uta, not the first one.